# how to call javascript function from Controllers file in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to call javascript function from Controllers file in MVC ?

Answer (score 1):

You CAN call it directly if you are using ajax.

Page A -> Ajax -> Controller -> Return javascript which invokes a method in Page A

```
    public ActionResult MyAjax(string message)
    {
        return JavaScript(string.Format("methodInPageA('{0}');", message.Replace("'", "\\'")));
    }
```

It might work without ajax too, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: WHAT is not working? How do you invoke the controller method? What result do you get? I'm using this solution myself in different projects. As I said: It might only work with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to call it directly you will have to call the javascript function onLoad document or other page event (like button click or something)

Comment: in mvc, onload is not working that i know but it's one class file only so it doesn't work.Here i have "  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(@@@@@@,this.GetType(),"setMenuItem","setMenuItem();",true); "

Answer (score 0):

**You can call JavaScript as well as content methods**

```
 public ActionResult Java_Script(){
      return JavaScript("Message");
 }
```

Comment: Could you clarify why you inverted the edit an April 20 which correctly formatted the code? you inverted back to incorrect code formatting!